# c++ imgui can not find glfw

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, imgui

I am trying to integrate imgui in my existing project. My project uses cmake and glfw for the window. It works and runs and when I run it a window shows.

Now I added the imgui files to my project and in the file `imgui_impl_glfw.cpp` I am getting the error `'GLFW/glfw3.h' file not found`. The error is in the include for glfw (`#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`). In another file in the project I am already using this same import and there it is working.

Does anybody have any idea why it can not find the import in the imgui file?

My cmake file looks like this btw (imgui related stuff at the bottom):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(aprum)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(src)
include_directories(src/engine/vendor)
include_directories(src/engine)
add_executable(aprum src/application/Application.cpp src/engine/logger/Logger.cpp src/engine/logger/Logger.h src/engine/logger/LogLevel.cpp src/engine/logger/LogLevel.h src/engine/graphics/shader/Shader.cpp src/engine/graphics/shader/Shader.h src/engine/graphics/renderer/Renderer.cpp src/engine/graphics/renderer/Renderer.h src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexBuffer.cpp src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexBuffer.h src/engine/graphics/renderer/IndexBuffer.cpp src/engine/graphics/renderer/IndexBuffer.h src/application/Game.cpp src/application/Game.h src/engine/graphics/window/Window.cpp src/engine/graphics/window/Window.h src/engine/IGame.h src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexArray.cpp src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexArray.h src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexBufferLayout.cpp src/engine/graphics/renderer/VertexBufferLayout.h src/engine/graphics/shader/ShaderProgram.cpp src/engine/graphics/shader/ShaderProgram.h src/engine/logger/GLErrorHandler.cpp src/engine/logger/GLErrorHandler.h src/engine/vendor/stb_image/stb_image.h src/engine/vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp src/engine/graphics/texture/Texture.cpp src/engine/graphics/texture/Texture.h)

# glfw
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(aprum glfw)
target_link_libraries(aprum ${GLFW_STATIC_LIBRARIES})

if (APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(aprum "-framework OpenGL")
endif()

#glew
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(aprum GLEW::GLEW)

#imgui
set(IMGUI_PATH  "src/engine/vendor/imgui")
file(GLOB IMGUI_SOURCES ${IMGUI_PATH}/*.cpp)
add_library("ImGui" STATIC ${IMGUI_SOURCES})
target_include_directories("ImGui" PUBLIC ${IMGUI_PATH})
target_link_libraries(aprum ImGui)
```

Comment: Which platform are you building on? Do you have glfw3 installed? (or connan?)

Comment: @elcuco I am building on a mac. I have glfw3 installed and I am succesfully using it in another place in the project.

Comment: I tried adding imgui_impl_glfw.cpp and imgui_impl_glfw.h to my  add_executable list. This made the error go away in my idea (clion) for some reason but does not actually fix the error while building.

Comment: The target `aprum` links with `${GLFW_STATIC_LIBRARIES}`, which contains GLFW libraries and, probably, include directories. The target `ImGui` does NOT link with GLFW. so its include directories are not accessible for it. Because `imgui_impl_glfw.cpp` is part of the library, then it cannot locate GLFW headers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're right that was the problem! Thank you so much for helping. Your explanation made me understand the linking of libraries and my own project a little better :)